# Typescript cannot pick the correct type for the payload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I have this issue where I get the typing error that:

> ```
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Subject | Subject[]'.
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Subject[]'.
> ```

This is the whole file

```
const initialState = [] as Subject[];

type Action = {
    type: string;
    payload: Subject | Subject[];
}

const reducer = (state: Subject[] = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SUBJECTS":
            return action.payload;
        case "ADD_SUBJECT":
            return [...state, action.payload];
        case "REMOVE_SUBJECT":
            return state.filter((subject) => subject.id !== action.payload.id);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

If i remove the "Subject[]" as a possible type of the payload, the error dissapears, but I really connot understand why it wouldn't pick the Subject as the type and allow me to use the "id" property that it has.

I tried removing the Subject[], which works, but I cannot go forward without allowing an array as an input.

Comment: Where is the declaration for Subject?

Comment: Can you add Subject interface ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a type guard function to tell typescript that payload is Array of Subjects or this is just a Subject, like that:

```
function isSubject(payload : Subject | Subject[]): payload is Subject {
  return 'any property from Subject' in payload
}
function isSubjectArray(payload : Subject | Subject[]): payload is Subject[] {
  return Array.isArray(payload)
}
```

And add it under `case "REMOVE_SUBJECT":`

```
case "REMOVE_SUBJECT":
  if (isSubject(payload))
  return state.filter((subject) => subject.id !== action.payload.id);
```

I hope that I helped you :)
If you want to learn more about advanced types, check this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a possibility that the payload attribute is an array, so the id attribute would be inside one of the array positions and should be accessed as ...[x].id.

The same will happen if you put Subject | string, expecting it to be a string, you will get the same error.